# Using Worg.css , my table of contents is blocked by the source block created by org-mode

Tags: html, css, publish, org-mode

I am  learning to use org-mode to create the web pages. I use the Worg.css found on [gist](https://gist.github.com/mpenet/3130635). I really like the style of it, but there is a problem: the table of contents is blocked by the source code block, which is not very convenient for navigation. The official website have no such problem. I haven't set up my own webpage yet, so I will just give a [screen-shot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzZ3xLk8sH4CR0RtVmJvaDJxNlk/edit?usp=sharing) of the problem I am facing with.

I also tried other worg styles, which has the same problem.

Can anyone tell me how to fix it?

Comment: Other css is [worg-zenburn](http://orgmode.org/worg/style/worg-zenburn.css) and [this one](http://orgmode.org/worg/style/worg.css)

Comment: I encountered this problem and solved it. Have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Add this CSS code to your worg.css:

```
pre.src {
    position: static;
    overflow: visible;
    padding-top: 1.2em;
}
```

Then, your table of content won't be bl

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried put these 2 lines in your Export settings?:

`#+INFOJS_OPT: view:info toc:nil`

`#+STYLE: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="..." />`

Where ... is 1 or 2:

1. One of these following css scripts links: [if you want to use them online]

   - http://orgmode.org/org.css
   - http://orgmode.org/worg/style/worg.css
   - http://orgmode.org/worg/style/worg-classic.css
   - http://orgmode.org/worg/style/worg-zenburn.css
   - http://orgmode.org/worg/code/org-info-js/
2. Or download them [so that using a local copy if you don't want to be be dependent on the site where the css script is host] put in a css directory within your project dir and call the script by writing or correcting the style line as folllowing:

`#+STYLE: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/my-favourite-css-sheet.css" />`

Then export it as usually.

Comment: Thanks, fOllow your procedure. When I add the first line of your code into my publish setup, the floating table of contents is gone([SEE](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzZ3xLk8sH4CM3Nqay15c0dSOTQ/edit?usp=sharing)), that's not what I really want.  I just want the floating content will not be blocked by the Source-code block, as I have shown in the question's screen shot picture. About your second line, I have already added it to my setup, except that I am using org-mode 8.2.5f. I have changed #+STYLE to #+HTML_HEAD.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me for fixing this globally was **removing the default style** via:

```
(setq org-html-head-include-default-style nil)
```

The way to do this and other global org export style modifications [has changed as of Org 8.0](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-8.0.html#sec-5-1).

For example, what worked for me for global changes was:

```
(setq org-html-head "<link rel='stylesheet'
  href='http://orgmode.org//worg/style/worg.css' type='text/css' />")
```

And this no longer works:

```
(setq org-export-html-style-include-default nil)
(setq org-export-html-style "<link rel='stylesheet' 
   href='http://orgmode.org//worg/style/worg.css' type='text/css' />")
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem recently too, came across to this question, and surprisingly, none of the answers worked for me. I later found that I need to add the following into my `.css` file:

```
#table-of-contents {
    z-index: 1;
}
```